# Is there a dock, that works as a gnome panel applet?

Tags: 10.10, gnome-panel, dock

Is there a dock, that works as a gnome panel applet, so I can put it into a panel alongside with other applets and indicators in one line?

I use Ubuntu 10.10

Answer (score 3):

I think [DockbarX](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/DockbarX?content=101604) is what you are looking for. It is an icon based dock that works as a panel applet. You can install it from a [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~dockbar-main/+archive/ppa).

Comment: Hey, DockbarX looks pretty good too! Haven't seen this yet. Does seem to be "inline" with gnomepanel

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you really want, however:

From this post, it seems that AWN can use the indicators and replace the Gnome-Panel.
http://www.webupd8.org/2010/06/indicator-applet-now-available-in-avant.html

NOTE: I have not tested this myself. To remove Gnome Panels, open a terminal and run:

> gconftool-2 --type=list --list-type=string --set /desktop/gnome/session/required_components_list '[windowmanager,filemanager]'

I think to fix you could run:

> gconftool-2 --recursive-unset /desktop/gnome/session/required_components_list

Comment: I am familiar with AWN (used to use it with XFCE), it won't provide the effect I'd like (parabolic zoom). And I don't want to remove Gnome Panel, I just wan't to put the dock on the same horizontal line (so that dock will be in screen's upper-left corner, and standard panel indicators and tray to be on their usual place). Actually I just want to replace a row of launcher applet icons with a doc with the only intention for it to show fancy "parabolic zoom" effect.

Comment: I don't want a full-featured dock as this would break unification - some programs will launch and "live" in a dock, some (as OpenOffice) will go to taskbar, some (as Skype) to systray. I'd only be willing to use a full-featurd dock if all and every application would be compatible with it.

Comment: You can move the Gnome panel to the right by alternate clicking the top panel, choose properties, and uncheck expand. Then simply move it to the right side of the screen by clicking and dragging on one of the ends. Perhaps a dock might co-exist with it then.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't a panel applet, but it does hide if you want: [Docky](http://wiki.go-docky.com/index.php?title=Welcome_to_the_Docky_wiki).

Comment: +1 to docky. Recommend you use gnome-do if you're not already, comes with docky branch.